# How to determine boost::optional's (and other) API's?

Tags: c++, boost, c++14

I was trying to go through the [boost optional](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_83_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html) documentation, and I find this with all of the boost docs in that I can't find a clear API definition.  I want to determine:

1. Is there is an `operator&` defined and if it checks for validity of the object?
2. How can I find API information for other boost classes?

Comment: Why use boost optional when C++ has [std::optional](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional) ? My advice before you dive into boost, first learn the standard library. The rest of boost api can be found at boost's website

Comment: Starting at the page you linked to, click on the [`Reference`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_83_0/libs/optional/doc/html/optional/reference.html) link and go through the various headers. In this case, you want [`<boost/optional/optional.hpp>`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_83_0/libs/optional/doc/html/boost_optional/reference/header__boost_optional_optional_hpp_/header_optional_optional_refs.html#reference_operator_template_spec)

Comment: @PepijnKramer, because we're using c++14 and std::optional is c++17.

Comment: @Adrian Yes that's an understandable reason :) So I tagged your question C++14 too (it avoids confusion like this)

Comment: @RemyLebeau, how did you get there?  I went through all of the links on the page posted and I didn't see that.

Comment: @Adrian from the page you linked to, I went to the [Reference](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_83_0/libs/optional/doc/html/optional/reference.html) page and clicked on [`<boost/optional/optional.hpp>`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_83_0/libs/optional/doc/html/optional/reference/header__boost_optional_optional_hpp_.html), then clicked on the [`R`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_83_0/libs/optional/doc/html/boost_optional/reference/header__boost_optional_optional_hpp_/header_optional_optional_values.html#reference_operator_template) link next to the `class optional` forward declaration.

Comment: @Adrian There is also a link to see the [full code of `boost/optional/optional.hpp`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_83_0/boost/optional/optional.hpp), too.

Comment: Helpful comments aside, I believe that a question about "how to find resources online" is off-topic.

Comment: @DrewDormann, I disagree.  Not being able to find this information from the boost site has been a thorn in my side for a while now.  I think that this is important information to share with other devs.

Comment: @Adrian I posted interactive discovery.

Comment: Sorry @RemyLebeau, I thought I had gone though that link already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways, see e.g.:[image]

Note that recently a powerful search box is added that searches all library code and documentation.

Note that the addressof-operator couldn't be safely overloaded in portable code (although given alignment restrictions and `[[no_unique_address]]` in C++20 might change the equation?).

Comment: normal quality animation https://imgur.com/a/mEU7QbE